# Redirect Main domain and subdomain from http to https

Tags: https, htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to redirect these sub domains and main domain from http to https and sub blogs too.

**Home directories**

- WWW (Wordpress):  `/home1/placehq5/public_html/.htaccess`
- My Somadome (PHP):    `/home1/placehq5/public_html/my`
- Kiosk site (HTML):    `/home1/placehq5/public_html/kiosk`

Webserver is Apache version 2.2.31 (on Linux)

please correct this htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://somadome.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www[.].+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://somadome.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

in this picture first column is how my urls are right now, 2nd column is what i want after htaccess rules, 3rd coulmn is what iam getting after applying these rule below:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to apache config and you will have redirect of all web sites which do nto use https to ssl/tls

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: its shared server hosting , cant edit httpd.conf file, dot have access to it. :(
can you write rule iin htaccess file ?

Comment: In such case add this `.htaccess` in every directory you have

Comment: okay , i will try this. "In such case add this .htaccess in every directory you have"